# Defer iframe loading so no broswer loading indication is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an html page with a pretty heavy iframe embedded there. I need to start loading that iframe after everything is already loaded in order not to block the whole page loading. I've tried setting its `src` attribute with JS after everything else is done. But when I do it this way the browser tab still says the loading is in process (there's a spinner instead of the favicon). How can I prevent that effect and load that iframe "silently"?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following (also using jQuery):

```
$('iframe').hide().attr('src', 'http://example.com').load(function() {
    $(this).show();
}
```